# SQL insert all data to bridge table, (many to many)

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I Have two table like below ;

X table ;

```
+---+----------+
| id| value    |
+---+----------+
| 1 | x value1 |
+---+----------+
| 2 | x value2 |
+---+----------+
| 3 | x value3 |
+---+----------+
```

Y table ;

```
+---+----------+
| id| value    |
+---+----------+
| 1 | y value1 |
+---+----------+
| 2 | y value2 |
+---+----------+
| 3 | y value3 |
+---+----------+
```

And I have created new table(x_y table)which has foreign keys for x and y tables ;

And I want to add all data related to each other to new table like below; 
x_y table

```
+----+------+------+
| id | x_id | y_id |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 2  | 1    | 2    |
+----+------+------+
| 3  | 1    | 3    |
+----+------+------+
| 4  | 2    | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 5  | 2    | 2    |
+----+------+------+
| 6  | 2    | 3    |
+----+------+------+
| 7  | 3    | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 8  | 3    | 2    |
+----+------+------+
| 9  | 3    | 3    |
+----+------+------+
```

how can I add value like this to third table on postgresql script.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a `cross join` and a `row_number` that generates id's.

```
select row_number() over(order by x.id,y.id) as id,x.id as x_id,y.id as y_id
from x
cross join y
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the new table is defined with `id` as a serial column.  If so, you would insert the data by doing:

```
insert into x_y (x_id, y_id)
    select x.id, y.id
    from x cross join
         y
    order by x.id, y.id;
```